# Generating random numbers in a list of probabilities, and failing the roll if the line is taged with "false"

Tags: excel, vba, probability

I've seen some answers similar to mine but here is my problem:

It's a game.

I have a list of quests:

[image: Quests]

The sum of chances (col J) is 90% cause i want to fail in 10% of times.

I'm trying to build a dynamic code that check all these quests (that can be added more in time), **AND** check the column "ON_PROGRESS".

If column "on progress" is tagged with 1 (0 or 1), the quest cannot be rolled and it will add it % to the 10% failure that I already have.

Another point is, the list will not be arranged like that (the higher prob to lower). Because I will add more at the end of the list (higher or lower prob)

(tried my best at the explanation)

Edit:

I want the code to return me which quest I rolled (QUEST_ID in this case)

RandomQuest()

result = 2

But with the conditions above.

Comment: I think you forgot to actually ask a question. What do you need help with exactly?

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you are asking. Are you trying write a VBA function to pick a random quest_id? What should such a function return if it "fails"? `#VALUE!`? Something else? Have you tried anything? If so, what?

Comment: i edited the question.

Comment: Your edit leaves the question unanswerable. The probabilities don't add up to 100%. They add up to *at most* 90% -- and you have given no information about what your function is supposed to do in the other at least 10% of the time.

Comment: in 10% cases return "failure".

Comment: And what about when you add more quests? Will you adjust all of the CHANCE_TO_GET down to total 90% every time?